# codelite debugger says 'Failed to locate gdb! at 'gdb' '

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, codelite

I'm new to c++ and trying to debug a small personal project in codelite manjaro. But whenever i click on 'debug' it says "Failed to locate gdb! at 'gdb'".When i checked in the 'debugger options' as expected no debugger path was specified.I think the error is due to this.I even attached a screenshot.Please help me.
[debugger error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7WYb.png)

Comment: Did you install `gdb` via your distribution's package manager?

Comment: check if gdb is installed with `which gdb`, then if it provides a path, use this one in your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Setting--> Build Settings and confirm the path for Gdb. In Ubuntu for my case it is /usr/bin/gdb (you can actually traverse through the folder manually to see if the actual gdb file is there